# how to get all the last level term id's of taxonomy in drupal 7?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

i have a  taxonomy

```
 State
      - district 1
          -block 1
            -village 1
            -Village 2
          -block 2
          -block 3
      - district 2
      - district 3
```

How to get all the term id's of all the villages in a state?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function get_term_depth($tid) {
  $limit = 5; // level of your term 
  $depth = 0; 
  while ($parent = db_select('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 't') ->condition('tid', $tid, '=') ->fields('t') ->execute() ->fetchAssoc()) {
    $depth ++;
    $tid = $parent['parent'];
    if ($depth > $limit) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return $depth;
}
?>
```